# Error trying to use nump frombuffer function on a large bytes object

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to pass a very, very long bytes object in numpy frombuffer, and it is giving me the following error:

ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size

Is there a flag I am missing? How can I specify and larger buffer size?

Edit: The format is like:

```py
x = b'\xdc\x08....\x01'
y = np.frombuffer(x)
```

Comment: default dtype is `float`, that's 8 bytes per element (check the docs).  What's `len(x)`.  `x` is the buffer the error is talking about.

Comment: so I should make the call frombuffer(x, count = len(x)) ?

Comment: No!  Read what the `count` specifies.  As a default it will read the whole buffer. With a float dtype the `len` of the buffer has to a multiple of 8.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, dtype is the return character, which is float, so where does the length fit? I understand count is just how much to read, so I understand I shouldn't use that flag. But dtype is the return type, so I'm not sure where the length of the buffer is involved.

Comment: Ah, I see, so the length of the buffer has to be a multiple of 8? So would a solution be to pad it until it reaches a multiple of 8 length?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it what type of data it is, and if it's an array, what is the array shape.  For example

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1,2,3],[2,4,6]]
npa = np.array(a)
x = npa.tobytes()
y = np.frombuffer(x, dtype = npa.dtype.name).reshape(npa.shape)
# check to see that y is the same as npa
```